# How can I re-assign an auto-increment primary key value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Is it possible to set the value of an auto-increment field? If a record is deleted with primary key 5, but the current auto-increment count is 10, is there any way to re-insert that record with its primary key still remaining at 5 (instead of 11)? I am trying to do this with Entity Framework 4.1 in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there were several good suggestions here, I came to realize several things while working with the solution to this question. The disclosure that the database was a MySQL perhaps would have helped here but I did not at the time realize the difference would be so substantial. In fact, in MySql there is no lock against inserting into an auto-increment primary key. As a result, this code works to insert a record with a primary key less than the current value of the auto-increment index:

```
        var sql = @"INSERT INTO Work (
            WorkId ,
            LotId ,
            Description ,
            )
            VALUES (
            '5',  '5', 'This Works'
            );";
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
        }
```

Properly inserting a record with the index of 5, even if the current auto-increment count is at 11.

Comment: There are some who would wonder why if ever this would be necessary. Indeed, it is rare for this case to occur, and my use of it will be to implement a restoration function where a record may be restored with its original primary key.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can also use

```
Set Identity_Insert TableName ON 
 Update your Id value
Set Identity_Insert TableName OFF
```

Comment: This seems to be a very good suggestion. I will have to figure out how to run this raw SQL in C# and then if it works I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: I got this error: `Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown system variable 'Identity_Insert'`

Comment: `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Set Identity_Insert Work Insert ON");`

Comment: @TravisJ punch me if you can...I just updated my answer...I typed an additional Insert in the statement...sorry :(...this should work now..

Comment: `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Set IDENTITY_INSERT Work ON");` still throws same error :(

Comment: That command was not valid when I tried it. However, I may have found out why Identity_Insert does not work. Apparently, this is a MSSQL specific functionality and MySql allows explicit inserts. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: See my answer for the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from **Tom Haigh**:

> You could drop the primary key column and re-create it. All the ids
>   will then be reassigned, I assume in the order in which the rows were
>   inserted.
>
> However, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, especially if you
>   have other tables that hold a foreign key to this table. If so you
>   would need to update those fields as well, in which case dropping and
>   recreating the column wouldn't be a good solution. You could instead
>   re-name the column, remove the autoinc/primary key property, then
>   create a new autoinc primary key column. You then would have both the
>   old and new ids which you could use to update such foreign keys.

Comment: I had actually read that person's answer before, and it seemed then and now to be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the [identity specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms188059.aspx). Your primary key would stay intact but you could insert a new record with an ID of your choice.
After you have inserted the record you would like to re-enable the identity specification.